# Error while testing the raise of self-defined exceptions (using assertRaises())

Tags: python, exception

I am creating tests for a python project. The normal tests work just fine, however I want to test if in a certain condition my function raises a self-defined exception. Therefor I want to use assertRaises(Exception, Function). Any ideas?

The function that raises the exception is:

```
def connect(comp1, comp2):
    if comp1 == comp2:
        raise e.InvalidConnectionError(comp1, comp2)
    ...
```

The exception is:

```
class InvalidConnectionError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, connection1, connection2):
        self._connection1 = connection1
        self._connection2 = connection2

    def __str__(self):
        string = '...'
        return string
```

The test method is the following:

```
class TestConnections(u.TestCase):
    def test_connect_error(self):
        comp = c.PowerConsumer('Bus', True, 1000)
        self.assertRaises(e.InvalidConnectionError, c.connect(comp, comp))
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\t5ycxK\PycharmProjects\ElectricPowerDesign\test_component.py", line 190, in test_connect_error
self.assertRaises(e.InvalidConnectionError, c.connect(comp, comp))
File "C:\Users\t5ycxK\PycharmProjects\ElectricPowerDesign\component.py", line 428, in connect
raise e.InvalidConnectionError(comp1, comp2)
InvalidConnectionError: <unprintable InvalidConnectionError object>
```

Comment: The `__init__` method of `InvalidConnectionError` is misspelled as `__int__`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. However it was only wrong in the code here, not in my actual files. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`assertRaises` expects to actually [*perform* the call](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises). Yet, you already perform it by yourself, thereby throwing the error before `assertRaises` actually executes.

```
self.assertRaises(e.InvalidConnectionError, c.connect(comp, comp))
# run this ^ with first static argument ^ and second argument ^ from `c.connect(comp, comp)`
```

Use either of those instead:

```
self.assertRaises(e.InvalidConnectionError, c.connect, comp, comp)

with self.assertRaises(e.InvalidConnectionError):
    c.connect(comp, comp)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. I accepted your answer!